# Can someone help to prove that following is a convex function

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

we have to prove that $\Phi(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\phi(x)$ where $\phi(x)$ is an increasing function $x\geq0$,I want to prove it by definition of convex function,
I tried but don't know what to do after this,
$\Phi(\alpha x + \beta y)=\int_{0}^{\alpha x+\beta y}\phi(t)dt$ now how to proceed after this.

Comment: I am not allowed to take derivative ,but by definition I have no idea idea how to proceed after that step.

Comment: @CalvinKhor There is no characterization in terms of the (classical) derivatives, unless we also assume some differentiability, which is not given here, and in fact does not follow

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich oh, that was sloppy of me, sorry. sorry to OP as well